# One django installation different users per site

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

How can I have different users for different sites with django.
My application should look like this:

```
a.mydomain.com
b.otherdomain.com
```

Users should be bound to the domain, so that a.mydomain.com and b.otherdomain.com have different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [auth](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) setup, you could create separate custom permissions, one per domain, and check if the current user has the permission for the current domain -- see the "custom permissions" section in the auth doc in question.